# post api calling in swift to send the parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have done one api calling to add the product to cart. And in button action i am doing this api calling.I need to send some particular parameters to api .But when i use postman code .Its throw many error in my code :

```
func addtocartapicalling ()
{


    let headers = [
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "4c933910-0da0-b199-257b-28fb0b5a89ec"
    ]

    let postData = NSData(data: "{
        "cartType" : "1",
        "cartDetails" : {
        "customerID" : "u",
        "cartAmount" : "6999",
        "cartShipping" : "1",
        "cartTax1" : "69",
        "cartTax2" : "",
        "cartTax3" : "",
        "cartCouponCode" : "",
        "cartCouponAmount" : "",
        "cartPaymentMethod" : "",
        "cartProductItems" : {
        "productID" : "9",
        "productPrice" : "6999",
        "productQuantity" : "1"
        }
    }
}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://api.php")!,
                                  cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.HTTPBody = postData

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        println(error)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        println(httpResponse)
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
}
```

[image]

See my above code, is there any api calling.Please help me out.

Thanks

```
  let string = "{\"cartType" : "1" + "cartDetails" : { "customerID" : "u", + "cartAmount" : "6999", + "cartShipping" : "1", + "cartTax1" : "69", + "cartTax2" : "", + "cartTax3" : "", + "cartCouponCode" : "", + "cartCouponAmount" : "", + "cartPaymentMethod" : "",} + "cartProductItems" : { "productID" : "9", + "productPrice" : "6999", + "productQuantity" : "1"  }" }"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy code from somewhere else and expect it to magically work.  Main issue is you can't split a literal string over multiple lines in Swift.  Either put it in one line or add multiple literal strings together over multiline.  For example...

```
let string = "{ \"cartProductItems\" : " +
        "{\"productID\" : \"9\"," +
        "\"productPrice\" : \"6999\"}}"

let postData = NSData(data: string.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Once you've fixed this most of your other errors you should be able to fix by clicking the error itself and Xcode will fix items for you like `NSURLSession has been renamed URLSession`

Comment: i tried to write like your solution.But still some error in that line.Like asking me to add commas, like that

Comment: That's not enough information for me to help you.  You'll need to update your answer with your new code.

Comment: please check my updat

Comment: You didn't apply my example.  Also I would highly recommend you start with some basic Swift tutorials regarding strings and string literals.    Good luck.